# getframe doesn't grab the updated figure

Tags: matlab

After creating a patch object

```
ball = patch(fv,'FaceColor',       [0.8 0.8 1.0], ...
        'EdgeColor',       'none',        ...
        'FaceLighting',    'gouraud',     ...
        'AmbientStrength', 0.15);
```

I set some rotation parameters and rotate the image.

```
omega_axis = [-1;1;0];
omega_mag = 8;
Img_iter = getframe;
handles = ball;

for i=1:10
     rotate(handles,omega_axis, omega_mag);
     pause(.001)
     Img_iter = getframe;
 end
```

Whenever I use `imshow(Img_iter.cdata)`, I get the first frame. It looks like getframe doesn't understand that I rotated the object in the image. What have I done wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace your `pause(.001)` by `drawnow`. It will force a refresh, and `getframe` will work properly.

Comment: I think I misdiagnosed what my problem was. The rest of my code turns the image I got from getframe to grayscale `image = getframe, rgb2gray(image.cdata)`, and then I was summing those images. It turns out that by summing the images, I'm just whiting out the whole thing and I need to scale the images. So I scaled down the images that were looped, but didn't scale down the first image acquired, so it looked like it was just the first image at the end of the loop. I'll mark yours as correct, because that did solve the problem I was asking (that was an issue earlier). Thanks!

Comment: OK, thanks. Next time, be sure to post all your code :)